# How to show an element only in this block?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is such a construction:

```js
$('ul li').click(function()
{
    $('.hide').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass("hide-open");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Пункт <div class="hide">Это скрыто</div></li>
  <li>Пункт <div class="hide">Это скрыто</div></li>
  <li>Пункт <div class="hide">Это скрыто</div></li>
</ul>
```

When you click on one item, all are toggled together. How to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.children()` method allows us to search through the children

use `$(this).children()`  open one item

```js
$('ul li').click(function () {
    $(this).children().slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass("hide-open");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>Пункт <div class="hide">Это скрыто</div></li>
<li>Пункт <div class="hide">Это скрыто</div></li>
<li>Пункт <div class="hide">Это скрыто</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use the [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method like:

```
$(this).find('.hide').slideToggle(300);
```

## Example:

```js
$('ul li').click(function()
{
    $(this).find('.hide').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass("hide-open");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    Пункт
    <div class="hide">Это скрыто 1</div>
    <div class="hide">Это скрыто 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Пункт
    <div class="hide">Это скрыто A</div>
    <div class="hide">Это скрыто B</div>
    <div class="hide">Это скрыто C</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Пункт
    <div class="hide">Это скрыто</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```